# How do I implement a global variable?

Tags: c, gcc, global-variables

**What I need help with: Passing an integer value that is in file2.c to file3.c via global variable using file1.h**

Hello, I am having an issue using a global variable to identify one of the ports I'm using on a cipher text project. Its pretty big, so I have just added the code snippets which address my issue.

What I am currently using to compile: gcc -o executable3 file2.c file1.h (this works)

and my second line (doesnt work): gcc -o executable3 file3.c

My Error message when compiling: undefined reference to `GLOBALVARIABLE'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

My file1.h file:

```
 ifndef FILE1_H
 define FILE1_H
 include <stdio.h>
 include <stdlib.h>
 extern int *GLOBALVARIABLE;
 endif
```

My file where I initialize the GLOBALVARIABLE value and set it equal to the port number (file 2):

```
#include "file1.h"
#define SIZE  128000
int *GLOBALVARIABLE;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;

portno = atoi(argv[1]);
GLOBALVARIABLE = &portno;
```

File that causes compiling conflict stated above (file 3):

```
#include "file1.h"
#define SIZE  16000
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, portno;
portno = atoi(argv[3]);
if (portno == *GLOBALVARIABLE){
printf("Theres been a port error, you are using the wrong port for this 
command");
exit(1);
```

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: You're having two main functions() one in file2 and file3, it means it will create two executable? Isn't that you want to have only one executable?

Answer (score 1):

You're using your compiler in the wrong way. By default, `gcc` emits a runnable binary, that means it already does the linking step. When linking, all symbols (except those imported from shared objects) must be defined.

What you have to do is *only compile* your source files (option `-c`) into object files and then link together these object files:

```
gcc -c -ofile2.o file2.c             # <- compile
gcc -c -ofile3.o file3.c             # <- compile
gcc -oexecutable file2.o file3.o     # <- link
```

In practice, add flags enabling warnings, chosing a C standard, etc.

**edit**: As pointed out in the comments, `main` should only exist *once*. Which one would you expect to be executed otherwise?

---

Two more thoughts here:

1. Don't put header files (`.h`) on your compiler command lines. They are included in the source files where needed.
2. If you wanted to share a variable between two independent programs, this is not possible using `extern`. "global variables" only exist in the scope of *one* process. If you want to share data between processes, there's e.g. *shared memory*, *pipes*, etc. (google for them).